# Getting a value from dictionary into a modelitem atribute

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am new in the dictionary datatype in C#. I got this model item:

```
  public Dictionary<int, string> language { get; set; }
  public string languageChoice { get; set; }
```

Then in my controller I got this:

```
  [Route("{id}/settings")]
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetProjectSettings(Guid id)
  {
     var projectSettings = new ProjectSettings
     {
        Id = id,       
        language = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
                           {1,"English"},
                           {2,"Spanish"}},
        languageChoice = //get language by ID        

     };

     if (projectSettings != null)
     {
        return Request.CreateResponse<ProjectSettings>(HttpStatusCode.OK, projectSettings);

     }
     else
     {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Project not found");
     }
  }
```

I want to give the json object the integer and not the String of the language. How can I do that?

Kind regards

Comment: so you want `{ "1": "English" }` ?

Comment: Yeah for example but in the json object I want to have like this languageChoice: "1" and not languageChoice: "English"

Comment: Something like this: `[{"languageChoice":1},{"languageChoice":2}]`

Comment: yes but not in an Array

Comment: Better still, can you add the desired outputted json to your question please, so we know what we're aiming at...

Comment: "language": { "1": "English", "2": "Spanish" }, "languageChoice": "English", English must be 1

Comment: So in your question can you put `{ "language": { "1": "English" , "2": "Spanish" }, "languageChoice": "1" }`

Comment: @Fearhunter - Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: yes sir the solution of Callum did the trick thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change your existing `Dictionary<int, string>` then you can just create a new `Dictionary<int, int>` from it.

```
var alteredDictionary = languages.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Key);
```

Then do

```
 var projectSettings = new ProjectSettings
 {
    Id = id,       
    language = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
                       {1,"English"},
                       {2,"Spanish"}},
    languageChoice = alteredDictionary[1]// optional .ToString() if you want string        
 };
```

Where `1` is the language Id you want.